# How to trace the outgoing request call using wire shark

Tags: security, trace, wireshark

I'm working on windows azure project and trying to use out of box azure tool. This tool seems to make lots of outgoing request to azure APIs. Unfortunately, most of the IP addresses are blocked by our internal firewall. Security team has requested a range of or specific IP addresses so that they can open port.

I've tried to use Wireshark to track outgoing IP addresses. Sadly, there are so many stuff going on on the trace. Could someone help me how to setup/configure wireshark such that it logs the outgoing requests for specific application?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Wireshark can filter by application, it just looks at the network data.

Answer (score 1):

This tool is what you want. Just learn how to use Wireshark [filters](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865).
Take a look at [Petri](http://www.petri.co.il/) and read this blog:
[Microsoft Network Monitor - Part 1](http://www.petri.co.il/microsoft-network-monitor-part-1.htm)
I like to point to this [picture](http://www.petri.co.il/wp-content/uploads/08-network-monitor-default-layout.png).